# How to migrate Wordpress site with no domain (only IP url)

Tags: php, wordpress, ip, permalinks

My server currently has only IP url (no domain name). I transferred my wordpress website on this server.

But an issue came up, front page works good, but when I try to open any other page it shows "404 Not Found" error...

Usually on Wordpress I just update Permalinks settings and it disappears, but I suspect this has something to do with IP url, as the issue doesn't go away when I update Permalinks settings.

Please, suggest me a way to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: This is called migration. No matter you had a domain name or not, you need to properly migrate the site. https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: I think I did that properly. I used to do it at least 25 times, and haven't got issues like this before.

Comment: Because probably your previous sites never had serialization data issues, carefully ready "Changing Your Domain Name and URLs"

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll check that now and let you know If that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue before and i tried somethink like this which worked well. You also try.

- In permalinks settings first change permalink option to default/plain.

Then run your site and check the issue. It should work. But check with your case!

If it goes fine then modify permalinks as before.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that!